# Indicates the controller name calling in the beginform of a view in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developping an asp.net mvc application.
I have 2 controllers A and B which have each :

a get method called C which return a view containing a beginform element :

```
("C",CONTROLLER,FormMethod.Post)
```

a post method called C with different logic in each controller

To do this implementation, I have 2 use 2 views, even if both are identical except the CONTROLLER parameter which change depending of the controller get method.
I would like to use only one shared view, and to do that I would like to know if it's possible to replace the CONTROLLER parameter in my beginform element with a parameter
indicating the controller calling.

For the moment I have 2 views where the only difference is that :
first view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("C", "A", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
    ...
    }
```

second view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("C", "B", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Url.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("Controller")
```

will hand you the current controller name.